# objects' method lookup path (modules & method override)

Tags: ruby

I cannot figure out how come the object is so smart to disregard the following block of code even if performed for the first time.

The method it is searching for is on each module

```
class A
  include B,C,D,B
end
```

Does ruby keeps an array of module names on the side (as it obviously calls `D`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% I understand your question but I try my best...

Ruby actually remembers which modules are included into a class and merges these modules into the lookup path for methods. You can ask a class for its included methods my using `A.included_modules`

Methods from included modules are put on top of the modules defined in the current class. Please see this example:

```
class X
  def foo
    puts 'Hi from X'
  end
end

module AnotherFoo
  def foo
    puts "Hi from AnotherFoo"
    super
  end
end

class Y < X
  include AnotherFoo
end

y = Y.new
y.foo
# Hi from another foo
# Hi from X

class Y < X
  include AnotherFoo
  def foo
    puts "Hi from Y"
    super
  end
end

y.foo
# Hi from Y
# Hi from another foo
# Hi from X
```

You can see the method resolution order: the child class -> the included modules -> the parent class. You can also see that modules are always included only once. So if a class already includes a module, it will not be re-included again.

Comment: A.included_modules? worked for me good enough to tell me that ruby keeps an array of module names on the side and i'm guessing the first thing it does here is to go through all the elements of this array and see if something is wrong . Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with "if something is wrong"? Ruby has a well-defined method resolution order. Meaning the algorithm it uses to find the actual function you are calling call when mentioning its name. And as I said, the order is class -> included modules (tried in order) -> parent class. If one of these contains a method with the defined name, it is used and the search aborted.

Comment: Indeed, by saying that something may go wrong i am not mentioning that something is wrong, i'm just saying that apparently when we get to the moment of asking  a module if it responds to a message of some sort, what ruby does is to ask itself included_modules and then do someting as you did say previously 'an included module will not be re-introduced' Now, I understand the other part about the method-lookup path, though i was aware of how it works as it's quite straightforward. It's just I had all these modules declared

Comment: having the same name i was trying to guess why does my object neglect the module i have declared as last, even though it's already in. A.included_modules? did help.